# ¿como hago para saber en que campo de texto esta situado el cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs

estoy usando angularjs y necesito saber en que campo de texto esta ubicado el cursor?, tengo un problema, es que cree un teclado en pantalla y este escribe dependiendo de la campo de texto donde este el cursor ya que hay mas de tres campos de texto, ¿como hago para saber en cual de los tres esta el cursor para que cuando utilice este teclado los las letras se escriban en el campo de texto indicado?

este es mi teclado en pantalla:

```
                                <input type="button" value="3" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">




                <br><br>
                <input type="button" value="4" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">
                <input type="button" value="5" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">
                <input type="button" value="6" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">

                <br><br>
                <input type="button" value="7" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">
                <input type="button" value="8" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">
                <input type="button" value="9" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">

                <br><br>
                <input type="button" value="0" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">
                <input type="reset" value="." class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">
                <input type="button" value="←" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary">
```

y estos son los campos:

```
 <input id="inlineFormInput" type="number" placeholder="Monto" ng-model="actual3.monto" class="mx-sm-3 form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé, si es lo que realmente necesitas pero existe la directiva `ng-mouseover`

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-mouseover.asp

```
 <input ng-onmouseover="dondeEscribir= $event.currentTarget.id">
```

para guardar el id del input en la variable `dondeEscribir`, o directamente `$event.currentTarget` y te quedas con todo el elemento.

Comment: Si, encontré una solución, existe una directiva llamada ng-focus que asigna un valor a una variable justo cuando seleccionas el input, es como un identificador de si esta seleccionado o no, gracias por tu aporte amigo